# How do I break someone's heart?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

In English, "heartbreak" is a well-attested and living metaphor, with phrases like "I'm going to break his heart", "my heart is broken", "he looks broken-hearted", "he's dealing with heartbreak", "he's a heartbreaker", and hundreds of others.

Is there a Latin equivalent to these? The obvious would be *cor frangere* or *cor rumpere*, but that feels overly literal.

(By the grace of Venus Obsequens, I'm asking about this for a work of fiction, not for real life.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tibullus/Lygdamus, writing after the loss of his love Neaera, laments:

> *... **frangit** fortia **corda** dolor*
>
> ... pain **breaks** strong **hearts**

[Tibullus], *Elegies*, 3.2.6

Which confirms your own guess!

Comment: Er, not 'pain breaks strong hearts'? (_cor_ is neuter.)

Comment: @Tom Cotton Ugh, you're right, corrected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

***cor, cordis*** *neuter substantive* **heart** is also a well-attested basis for several metaphors in Latin. In Latin, however, the heart, and the ***praecordia, -ae,*** the midriff, is the seat of social harmony and memory as well as love and affection.

SUFFER HEARTBREAK

> ***cordoleo, -ere*** be heartbroken.
>   ***misericordia, -ae*** f. **I** sympathy
>   **II** appeals to pity.

SEAT OF SOCIAL EMOTION: added prefix

> *concordo*
>   *concors, concordis* adjective of the same mind.
>   *discors* discord
>   *discordia*

[missing in Classical Latin: *accors, succor* ]

THE MIND centre of mental activity

> *excors -dis* adj senseless, without intelligence.
>   *recordatio, -tionis*
>   *recordor, -ari* to bring back to mind

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a phrase corresponding to the English one(s) in frequency and tone, but here are some ideas:

- There is an ante- and post-classical word [*cordolium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=cordolium&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), "sorrow of heart".
- Ovid's *Remedia Amoris* is a poem about broken hearts, so I recommend reading it for inspiration in this direction.
  On a quick glance, I found these lines:

  > 15: *At si quis male fert indignae regna puellae*
  >   Any man who suffers from the rule of an unworthy girl
  >
  > 42: *quos suus ex omni parte fefellit amor*
  >   you who have been completely betrayed by love
  >
  > 54: *nec servum vitii pectus habere sui*
  >   and not to let the heart be a slave to one's own vice
  >
  > 105: *Interea tacitae serpunt in viscera flammae*
  >   Meanwhile silent flames creep inside
  >
  > 148: *Adfluit incautis insidiosus Amor*
  >   Love flows into the unexpecting